# Unable to convert date time to time and compare it with another date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm facing a weird issue and I can't understand what's wrong.
In my database I have a `datetime` field, which keeps some values like: `03.10.2012 11:25:06`
I need to convert it to `date` and compare it with another date. What I have tried without success is:

```
p1.value as City,
p2.value as Country,
p3.value as RequestNumber,
convert (datetime, convert (varchar, test.timestampmin, 101), 101) as timestampmin

from Process p
LEFT JOIN Parameter p1 on p1.ID=p.id AND p1.NAME = 'City'
LEFT JOIN Parameter p2 on p2.ID=p.id AND p2.NAME = 'Country'
LEFT JOIN PA_Parameter p3 on p3.ID=p.id AND p3.NAME = 'RequestNumber'

INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT min(Timestamp) as timestampmin, id as id
    FROM tasks
    GROUP BY id
) as test 
    ON test.id = p3.ID

where p.type='Event' and 
timestampmin = convert (datetime, convert (varchar, '06.18.2012', 101), 101)
```

The problem is that I can't compare the converted `datetime` with the `convert (datetime, convert (varchar, '06.18.2012', 101), 101)` which I'm using in the where clause.

What am I missing?

Comment: You sure like to use joins.

Comment: The database is not well designed, the slow joins are the only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply, you cannot access column aliases in the SELECT clause within the WHERE clause of the same query.

```
p1.value as City,
p2.value as Country,
p3.value as RequestNumber,
convert (datetime, convert (varchar, test.timestampmin, 101), 101) as timestampmin

from Process p
LEFT JOIN Parameter p1 on p1.ID=p.id AND p1.NAME = 'City'
LEFT JOIN Parameter p2 on p2.ID=p.id AND p2.NAME = 'Country'
LEFT JOIN PA_Parameter p3 on p3.ID=p.id AND p3.NAME = 'RequestNumber'

INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT min(Timestamp) as timestampmin, id as id
    FROM tasks
    GROUP BY id
) as test 
    ON test.id = p3.ID

where p.type='Event' and 
convert (datetime, convert (varchar, test.timestampmin, 101), 101)
   = convert (datetime, convert (varchar, '06.18.2012', 101), 101)
```

And if `test.timestampmin` is a datetime column, you can use this in the WHERE clause instead

```
where p.type='Event'
  and test.timestampmin >= '20120618'
  and test.timestampmin <  '20120619'
```